# Why the optimized prime number generator program take more time?

Tags: python, time-complexity, primes

I recently work on the prime number generator program and try to optimize the time complexity.

1. My first attempt is simple: iterate from `current_big_prime + 1` as `current_number` and in every iterate check from 1 to `current_number-1` to see if `current_number` is prime.
2. Then I realize it is sufficient that every check iterate(the inner loop) go until `sqrt(current_number)+1` instead of `current_number-1`, which should save a lot of time.

But the result is opposite: the optimized program is worse on time complexity.

Here is my program:

```py
#%% Prime Streaming (PG-13)
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

class Primes:
    @staticmethod
    def stream1():
        primes = []
        yield 2
        i = 3
        while True:
            is_prime = True
            for j in primes:
                if i % j == 0: 
                    is_prime = False
                    break
            if is_prime:
                yield i
                primes.append(i)
            i += 2
    @staticmethod
    def stream2():
        primes = []
        yield 2
        i = 3
        while True:
            is_prime = True
            for j in filter(lambda x: x < math.sqrt(i) + 1, primes):
                if i % j == 0: 
                    is_prime = False
                    break
            if is_prime:
                yield i
                primes.append(i)
            i += 2

def get_nth_prime1(n):
    s = Primes.stream1()
    cnt = 0
    for i in s:
        cnt += 1
        if cnt > n:
            break
    return i
def get_nth_prime2(n):
    s = Primes.stream2()
    cnt = 0
    for i in s:
        cnt += 1
        if cnt > n:
            break
    return i

s1 = Primes().stream1()
for i in range(20):
    print(next(s1), end=' ')
print()

s2 = Primes().stream2()
for i in range(20):
    print(next(s2), end=' ')
print()

t1 = timeit.timeit("get_nth_prime1(5000)",  
              "from __main__ import get_nth_prime1", number=1)
t2 = timeit.timeit("get_nth_prime2(5000)",  
              "from __main__ import get_nth_prime2", number=1)
print(f"check until n: {t1}\ncheck until sqrt(n): {t2}")
```

Comment: At the very least, pull `math.sqrt(i)` outside of the lambda so you're calculating it fewer times.

Comment: On top of what @BillLynch added, you can get rid of the filter expression as well which is expensive. From the `primes` list you are filtering the eligibile elements using the lambda expression everytime.

Comment: Please don't update your question to ask a follow up question, [such edits aren't appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal)

Comment: Are you asking about "time" as per the title or "time *complexity*" as per the body? These are different things and as far as I can tell the "time complexity" should be the same for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` doesn't stop early. It does filter out the numbers larger than the square root, but to do that, it still goes through *all* the numbers and tests them. It just doesn't pass the large ones on to you. So while you do save the cost for your `i % j == 0` for the large ones, you pay the larger filter/lambda cost for them instead. And for the small ones you pay it *additionally*.

You can instead use [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), that does do exactly what you were trying to do. It gives you the small numbers and entirely stops when it reaches the square root.

In my own testing, your code reported times ~1.7 seconds *without* `filter` and ~4.9 seconds *with* `filter`. With `takewhile`, it's ~0.15 seconds. And ~0.08 seconds if you use `lambda x: x < sqrt`, computing that limit only once, before the loop. A simple `if`+`break` as the other answer suggested is still faster, though, as it avoids the filter/lambda overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The `filter` operations costs `O(N)` and is unnecessary in this case. Instead we can do an `if` check and `break` the loop once it exceeds the square root.

You can read more about the filter operation here [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Here's the benchmark after the above optimisations:

```
check until n: 1.7345025209997402
check until sqrt(n): 0.10318170000027749
```

Also, as a bonus, do checkout the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm which is a lot more cleaner and faster.

Comment: After reaserch I am still confused. You said filter is O(N), but if check and break is also O(N).  I thought filter is lazy evaluation, so using filter will not cost too much overhead. However the cost difference is more than x10(actually on my machine it is x50). could you elaborate on it?

Comment: By "filter is lazy evaluation", do you mean (1) it checks and iterates only one element at a time, rather than building a list in one go, or (2) it stops as soon as it finds an element larger than `sqrt(i)`? (1) is true, but (2) is not. The check+break approach *does* achieve (2), so it's faster than a filter.